# Why does Python gives value error for below problem

Tags: python, list, arraylist, data-structures

Output screen:

```
enter the number of elements:3
1
23
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 18, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
>
```

Code :

```
arr =[]

def runninsum(arr):
    srr = []
    temp = 0
    summ = 0
    for i in arr:
        temp = i
        summ = summ +temp
        srr.append(summ)
    
    return srr
    
n = int(input("enter the number of elements:")) 
for j in range(0, n):
    ele =int(input())
    arr.append(ele)
print(arr)
    
    

num = runninsum(arr)   
print(num)
```

I'm trying to solve sum of 1d array question from Leetcode, while I'm appending the list I'm getting the value error. Why am I getting this issue?

Comment: The error message and code don't match your supposed output. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what's happening. You are effectively trying to do this: *int('')*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a SLIGHT modification

```
arr =[]

def runninsum(arr):
    srr = []
    temp = 0
    summ = 0
    for i in arr:
        temp = i
        summ = summ +temp
        srr.append(summ)
    
    return srr
    
n = int(input("enter the number of elements:")) 
for j in range(0, n):
    ele =int(input(""))     # <<============= HERE
    arr.append(ele)
print(arr)
    
    

num = runninsum(arr)   
print(num)
```

Comment: Instead of using a for loop to take the inputs, you can do this: `nums = list(map(int, input().split()))` to take multiple inputs in one line. And then check whether the given length and the length of the array are equal using this: `assert n == len(nums)`

Answer (score 0):

Your Code works fine.

The problem may come when you put input anything other than numbers. You may have pressed the "enter" button without any number in your error case. That's why the error said '' in the end.

To avoid such an error, you can write a try-block like the below.

```
arr =[]

def runninsum(arr):
    srr = []
    temp = 0
    summ = 0
    for i in arr:
        temp = i
        summ = summ +temp
        srr.append(summ)
    
    return srr
    
n = int(input("enter the number of elements:")) 
for j in range(0, n):
    while True:
        user_input = input('Enter an int element: ')
        try:
            ele = int(user_input)
        except ValueError:
            print(f"Invalid integer '{user_input}', try again")
        else:
            break
    arr.append(ele)
print(arr)
    
    

num = runninsum(arr)   
print(num)
```